# Scanf is not taking input of type double

Tags: c

This is the code i am running

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void main()    
{
 int i=0;
 double kl,x0,x1,xk;
 printf("enter kl");
 scanf("%lf",&kl);  
 printf("hello");
 for(x1=kl;((x1-x0)>2) || ((x1-x0)<-2);x0 );  
  {
   x0=x1;
   x1=(x0/2.0)+(kl/(2.0*x0));

   }
 printf("%lf",x1); 
 printf(" %lf ",(sqrt(kl)-x1));
}
```

after running `scanf` is not taking input. hello is not printed.

Comment: did you hit enter? enter is how it knows that you finished typing the number

Comment: yes, I did hit enter. I entered a simple number and hit enter and it is not running, it is not even printing hello,

Comment: it prints hello here, after I put the number in. Can you be more clear about what's happening? Is the console appearing with the "enter kl" message?

Comment: yes the console is showing enter kl, after that I have typed a number and pressed enter.

Comment: what is it printing? how far does it get? like i said, it works fine here

Comment: I tried removing for loop and then it is working but with for loop it is not running

Comment: You don't have a very sensible looking for loop, describe what numbers it's mean to iterate between.

Comment: `scanf` works, your code is stuck in the loop. Use `printf("hello\n")` to flush stdout otherwise it's not printed. to read a double you should use "%lg".

Comment: the code is for finding square root using newton raphson method.

Comment: The problem is that your loop runs forever, you should put print statements inside the loop for the values, to check that they're actually changing properly

Comment: also the for loop is less clear here than just using a while loop

Comment: can't we use %lg %lf and %le for double?

Comment: why is \n requires? in printf. It runs every time I use without \n

Comment: Can we use || in the for condition ?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not `scanf`, it is an infinite loop (your `for` loop has an empty body).

The compiler tells you that:

```
d:tmp diciu$ gcc -g test2.c
[..]
test2.c:11:44: warning: for loop has empty body [-Wempty-body]
 for(x1=kl;((x1-x0)>2) || ((x1-x0)<-2);x0 );  
                                           ^ this semicolon creates the empty body
```

Your semicolon at the end of the for loop tells the compiler to generate a for loop with an empty body.

While reading the code tells you the problem is in the `scanf` because you don't see the "hello" string being printed your assumption is incorrect; `stdout` if buffered and you're not seeing the string because you have not flushed the buffer; you can force a buffer flush by adding a line terminator (`printf("hello\n")`) or by flushing stdout (look up `fflush`).

Even if you miss the compiler warning, the problem is very easily spotted using a debugger.